# How to adjust the size of a PyQt window

Tags: python, pyqt, size

I have create a pyqt window, which contains a GridLayout. This GridLayout contains 4 pushbuttons.

When a resize the window manually with the mouse, the size of the pushbutton doesn't change to fit the new window size.

My objective is that the size of the button changes to fit the new window size, like in a responsive webpage.

I have already tried:

- Change the container
- Change the vertical and horizontal size policy of my button
- Add the grid as the ancestor of the pushbutton
  but nothing work

The .py generated from the .ui :

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(554, 415)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(7)
    MainWindow.setFont(font)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    self.centralwidget.setPalette(palette)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 90, 441, 291))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
    self.gridLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(20)
    self.gridLayout.setVerticalSpacing(19)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    self.title = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.title.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 271, 61))
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(190, 255, 216))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(136, 246, 180))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(55, 158, 96))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(169, 246, 199))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(190, 255, 216))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(136, 246, 180))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(55, 158, 96))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(169, 246, 199))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(190, 255, 216))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(136, 246, 180))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(55, 158, 96))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(41, 118, 72))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(83, 237, 144))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    self.title.setPalette(palette)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(29)
    self.title.setFont(font)
    self.title.setText("")
    self.title.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.RichText)
    self.title.setObjectName("title")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: you have indicated your attempts but you have forgotten to indicate your objective in addition to providing a [mre]

Comment: my objective is that the size of the button changes when i modify the window size in order to fit in it. Like in a responsive webpage

Comment: 1. Shouldn't you point that out in your question? 2. where is the MRE?

Comment: 1. It is in my question : "When a resize the window manually with the mouse, the size of the pushbutton doesn't change to fit the new window size.". 2. I use Qt Designer to create this window. Do you want the .py which is generate from the .ui ?

Comment: 1. the question has to be direct, 2. show what you have tried, if the files are only .ui then you must share the .ui. please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: I added the .py generated from the .ui and the objective in my question

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a QGridLayout and set the vertical button size policy to be "minimum":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer but it doesn't fix my issue. My buttons were already in a QGridLayout. I set the sizepolicy of the button on "minimum" as you said but the issue is still the same. (The button is cut when I resize the window, instead of resizing).

Here is my code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(498, 340)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    MainWindow.setPalette(palette)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(7)
    MainWindow.setFont(font)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(245, 245, 247))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(157, 157, 159))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(117, 118, 119))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(235, 236, 239))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 220))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)
    brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)
    self.centralwidget.setPalette(palette)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 110, 291, 201))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
    self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
```

Did I miss something ?